# what is this distortion?

Tags: amplifier, distortion

what is this distortion?

[image]

This is the circuit where it is derived

http://puu.sh/1xdew

As you can see, it looks like there is a problem in the negative half cycle, its not really a straight clip. The waveform is taken at the 8 ohm resistor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of observations:

(1) In your schematic, you show Q4 as an n-channel though the part number is for a p-channel.

(2) Also, in your schematic, Q4 appears to be "upside down", i.e., the drain is connected to the output rather than the source.

Answer (score 0):

It is 2<sup>nd</sup> harmonic distortion caused by asymmetry in the circuit. Its ability to sink current is less than its ability to source current.